# How to Get all product list from iTunes connect dynamically for inapp purchase, Is it possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am first time implementing the inapp purchase and right now i am inserting product id static in my app and through that i am retrieved product but is there any way to do this dynamically?
I am following ray wenderlich tutorial for inapp purchase.
and hare is my code.

```
 NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
 @"my Product id",
 @"my Product id",
 @"my Product id",
 @"my Product id",
 @"my Product id", 
 nil];
```

**EDIT:-**
I am also not getting products. and  I checked that all identifier i entered is correct.and bundle identifier for product plus provisioning is also correct. I also submitted binary to iTunes connect to test binary but still didn't get success!

Thanx in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you implement a simple web service that returns the product ids that your app currently supports?

Also, see this link for the list of things that can go wrong with products: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/